# Передать переменную в функцию в процессе ее выполнения Python

Tags: многопоточность, telebot, асинхронность, sleep

Есть следующий код телеграм бота:

```
from time import sleep
from config import *
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)


global started
started = False

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def game(message):
    menu = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    menu.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начать игру", callback_data ='start_game'))

    mess = ["Игра"]

    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, mess, reply_markup=menu)

    sleep(5)
    if not started:
        not_in_game(message)



def not_in_game(message):

    menu = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    menu.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начать игру", callback_data ='start_game'))

    mess = ["сделайте выбор"]

    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, mess, reply_markup=menu)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: 'start_game' == call.data)
def game_started(call):

    started = True
    mess = ["игра началась"]

    msg = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, mess)


bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Нужно, чтоб после нажатия кнопки "Начать игру", не выполнялся код после sleep в функции game и не запускалась функция not_in_game.
Я пытаюсь это реализовать через внешнюю переменную started, но этот способ не работает, функция not_in_game все равно выполняется.
Как правильно реализовать поставленную задачу?

Answer (score 0):

Тут проблема в том, что в методе `game_started(call)` python под переменной `started` понимает локальную, а не глобальную. Достаточно немного переделать код и будет работать:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: 'start_game' == call.data)
def game_started(call):
    global started  # добавлено
    started = True
    mess = ["игра началась"]

    msg = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, mess)
```

Но в целом использование глобальных переменных для такого очень плохая практика, чреватая усложнением поддержки и плавающими багами в будущем. Лучше поискать другие способы, как вариант, у TeleBot есть метод `register_next_step_handler` для регистрации дополнительного обработчика и если у первого отключить уведомление, то можно вторым обработчиком и проверить была ли нажата "новая игра". Далее псевдокод, не проверял у себя, если что:

```
from time import sleep
from config import *
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def game(message):
    menu = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    menu.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начать игру", callback_data='start_game'))

    mess = ["Игра"]

    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, mess, reply_markup=menu)

    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, not_in_game)

    sleep(5)
    if not msg.content_type:
        not_in_game(msg)

def not_in_game(message):
    menu = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    menu.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начать игру", callback_data='start_game'))

    mess = ["сделайте выбор"]

    msg = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, mess, reply_markup=menu)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: 'start_game' == call.data)
def game_started(call):
    mess = ["игра началась"]

    msg = bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, mess)

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!